# Can't show uploaded image with correct path

Tags: angular, angular6

When uploading an image, I would like to display a preview of the image and its path (e.g. `../assets/dist/upload/profil-sfgho91563005701768.jpg`).

**The template HTML looks like this:**

```html
<div>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
    </label>

    <button class="btn btn-success"
            [disabled]="!selectedFiles"
            (click)="upload()">
        Upload
    </button>

    <br/>
    <img src="{{displayImage()}}" style="max-width:30px"/>
    <br/>

    {{displayImage()}}
</div>
```

**The component.ts looks like this:**

```js
selectFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files.item(0)

  if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  } else {
    alert('invalid format!');
  }
}

upload() {
  this.progress.percentage = 0;
  this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);

  this.userService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload)
    .subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
      }
    })

  sessionStorage.getItem("fullNameFile");

  this.currentSelectedFile = "../assets/dist/upload/" + sessionStorage.getItem("fullNameFile");
  this.selectedFiles = undefined;
}


displayImage(): String {
  this.pathImage = "../assets/dist/upload/" + sessionStorage.getItem("fullNameFile");
  return this.pathImage;
}
```

[As seen in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfX0b.png), the produced path is synchronously correct after each upload.

However the image cannot be shown.
But when I put this url on src (`<img src="../assets/dist/upload/profil-mu1os1563004878566.jpg" style="max-width:30px"/>`), that works well.

How do I solve this issue?

Big thanks.

Comment: you need to change the path to correct url, for eg: http://localhost:4200/assets/dist/upload/profil-mu1os1563004878566.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try that:

```
url: string | ArrayBuffer;

selectFile(event:any)
    {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0])
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) =>
            {
                this.url = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }

        const file = event.target.files.item(0)

        if (file.type.match('image.*'))
        {
            this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('invalid format!');
        }
    }
```

and on html, try that:

```
<img [src]="url" style="max-width:30px">
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `img` can not find the image BEFORE it is uploaded. You need to the image to be uploaded first and then show the `img` once done.

You could create a `showImg` variable and then set it to true on subscribe and show the image.

template HTML:

```
<div>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
    </label>

    <button class="btn btn-success"
            [disabled]="!selectedFiles"
            (click)="upload()">
        Upload
    </button>

    <div *ngIf={{showImg}}>
        <img src="{{displayImage()}}" style="max-width:30px"/>
        {{displayImage()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
showImage: boolean = false;

...

upload() {
  this.showImage = false;
  this.progress.percentage = 0;
  this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);

  this.userService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload)
    .subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely uploaded!');

        this.showImage = true;

        sessionStorage.getItem("fullNameFile");
        this.currentSelectedFile = "../assets/dist/upload/" +  sessionStorage.getItem("fullNameFile");
        this.selectedFiles = undefined;
      }
    })
}

...
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Rust, thanks a lot for your reply. But I need display the image just **after** selecting it and **before** clicking on the button `upload`.